# JSON complex tree with PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I don't know how to do to extract the following JSON objects. I try to use foreach but it's not working. Could you help me?
Here the JSON file :

```
{
    "success":true,
    "moreDataAvailable":true,
    "ewons":
        [
            {
                "id":252459,
                "name":
                "eWON_TEST",
                "tags":
                    [

                        {
                            "id":107060,
                            "name":"TEMP_EXT",
                            "dataType":"Int",
                            "description":"Température extérieure",
                            "alarmHint":"",
                            "value":15.0,
                            "quality":"good",
                            "ewonTagId":1,
                            "history":
                                [
                                    {
                                    "date":"2016-05-09T16:06:49Z",
                                    "quality":"initialGood",
                                    "value":64.0
                                    },

                                    {
                                    "date":"2016-05-09T16:16:49Z",
                                    "quality":"initialGood",
                                    "value":6.0
                                    },

                                    {
                                    "date":"2016-05-09T16:21:49Z",
                                    "quality":"initialGood",
                                    "value":6.0
                                    }
                                ]
                        },

                        {
                            "id":107072,
                            "name":"TEMP_IN",
                            "dataType":"Int",
                            "description":"Température intérieure",
                            "alarmHint":"",
                            "value":22.0,
                            "quality":"good",
                            "ewonTagId":5,
                            "history":
                                [
                                    {
                                    "date":"2016-05-09T17:01:49Z",
                                    "quality":"initialGood",
                                    "value":22.0
                                    },

                                    {
                                    "date":"2016-05-09T17:06:49Z",
                                    "value":22.0
                                    },

                                    {
                                    "date":"2016-05-09T17:11:49Z",
                                    "value":22.0
                                    }
                                ]

                        }
                    ],
                "lastSynchroDate":"2016-12-16T15:21:22Z"
            }
        ]
}
```

In fact, I would like to display the history for each tags with the following information on each line :

```
['id'],['name'],['dataType'],['descritption'],['ewonTagId'],['id(from ewons)'],['name(from ewons)'],['date'],['quality(from history)'],['value']
```

I have the following code at this time but nothing I tried for the loop worked...

```
<?php
//Read JSON file
$filename ='fichier.json';
$json = file_get_contents($filename);

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($json,true);

// Loop trough the array
foreach(???) {
echo ???
}
?>
```

Comment: I try it this morning but I didn't success with :-(

Comment: There must be a 100 possible duplicates to this question. Do some searching in the JSON tag

Answer (score 0):

You need three foreach loops.

```
//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($json,true);

// Loop trough the array
foreach($data['ewons'] as $_ewon) {
    foreach ($_eown['tags'] as $_tag) {
        foreach ($_tag['history'] as $_history) {
           // now echo your data from $_ewon, $_tag and_history
           // do a var_dump or print_r if you're unsure about what's exactly in these variables
        }
    }
}
```